# Why can't I use 'dotnet run' with xUnit in C#?

Tags: c#, xunit

I'm creating an application which requires unit tests. I'm using the .NET xUnit-framework.

First, I initialized a new "Hello, World! class" with

```
dotnet new console
```

Then I added the unit test

```
dotnet new xunit
```

When I run `dotnet run` or `dotnet test`, I get this error:

```
 error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type thatcontains the entry point.
```

I read about there being a Main defined in the xUnit which interferes with the entry point in Program, but how would I be able to have these separated? That is, how would I be able to run both `dotnet run` and `dotnet test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to be able to run both `dotnet test` and `dotnet run` [here](https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/).

The problem is that a test project builds its own Program.cs file. You want to add following to your .csproj:

```
<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not run both "dotnet new console" and "dotnet new xunit" in the same directory. They are different projects and they have different entry point.

Comment: Oh, okay, so you're saying that I should make two completely different projects: one with the tests and one runnable version?

Comment: Exactly, you should make two projects and run projects separately. The console application with `dotnet run` and the test application with `dotnet test`.